# styled div lines disappear for print screen

Tags: html, css

So I've been putting together a handout for one of my classes. I did it in html so that i could insert content easily in the future.

A problem I ran into was when I went to print this page off, the lines wouldn't come up in the print screen. what i have are divs with a styled background that serve as the line one might write on. When i go to print these they are removed from print.

let me know if anybody knows what's up with this!

```css
body{
    margin:auto;
    
}



.page-container{
    margin:auto;
    padding:0 0 2em 0;
   
    grid-template-columns:repeat(8, 12.5%);
    grid-template-rows:repeat(4, auto);
    grid-template-areas: "header header header header header header header header"
                         "top top top top top top top top"
                         ". . main main main main . ."
                         "footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer";
    max-width:612pt;
    max-height:792pt;
    overflow-y: hidden;

    border-left:2px solid black;
    border-right:2px solid black;
}

.page-header{
    grid-area:"header";
    height:2pt;
}

.top{
    grid-area: top;
}

.page-title, .title-analyzing_for, .analysis-categories{
    text-align:center;
    
}

.page-title{   
    font-size:4rem;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    
}

.title-analyzing_for{
    margin:1.4em 0 0 0;
    font-size:1rem;
    
}

.analysis-categories{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;


    
    margin:1.4em auto 0 auto;
    max-width:70%; 

    overflow:hidden;
    justify-content: center;
    
    font-family: 'Sanchez', serif;
}

.category{
    display:block;
    min-width:5.875em;
    margin:0.6em 1.4em;
}


.lines_section{
    display:flex;
    grid-area: "main";
    flex-direction:column;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top:20pt;
    border: 2px solid pink;
}

.writing_space_component{
    width:100%;
    margin-top:7em;
    font-size:1.5rem;
}

.writing_space_component:nth-of-type(1){
    margin-top: 0;
}

.typed_writing{
    width:100%;
    height:1em;
    text-align:center;
}

.line{
    
    height:0.09em;
    width:85%;
    margin:2pt auto 0 auto;
    border-radius:1pt;
    background-color:black;
    
}
.line--dashed{

}

.pre_animation{
    
}

@media print{
    .page-container{
        border:none;
    }
    .lines_section{
        border:none;
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Sentence Analysis</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="A descri">
    <meta name="author" content="Chris Cormier">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway|Roboto+Condensed|Sanchez&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="page-container">
        <div class=""></div>
        <section class="top">
            <div class="page-title">Single-Factor<br>Sentence Analysis</div>
            <div class="title-analyzing_for">Analyzing for:</div>

            <div class="analysis-categories">
                <div class="category">S-V-O</div>
                <div class="category">Prepositions</div>
                <div class="category">Word Type</div>
                <div class="category">Pronoun Type</div>
                <div class="category">Clauses</div>
                <div class="category">S-V-O</div>
                <div class="category">Prepositions</div>
                <div class="category">Word Type</div>
                <div class="category">Pronoun Type</div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <main class="lines_section">
            <div class="writing_space_component">
                <div class="typed_writing">fdsafdsa</div>
                <div class="line"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="writing_space_component">
                <div class="typed_writing">fdsafdsa</div>
                <div class="line"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="writing_space_component">
                <div class="typed_writing">fdsafdsa</div>
                <div class="line"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="writing_space_component">
                <div class="typed_writing">fdsafdsa</div>
                <div class="line"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="writing_space_component">
                <div class="typed_writing">fdsafdsa</div>
                <div class="line"></div>
            </div>
        </main>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Protip: In Chrome DevTools select More Tools > Rendering > Emulate CSS media <---- set to print.  Super helpful for drafting HTML printables.

Comment: @GammaGames thanks mate, exactly what I was looking for! god bless ya'